# Error : E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: java, android, android-studio, runtime-error

The user supposed to select the domain he is good at "Maths" or "Info" and then a list is going to show a list of subjects depending on the domain that he selected and his level. But when the user selects one of the subjects and click on the button"OK" I get this error:

D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: android.example.easya, PID: 1153
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
at android.example.easya.edit_profil_vol$2$2.onClick(edit_profil_vol.java:223)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:109)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7555)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:469)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:963)

Here is the code the problem with the "OK" and "CLEAR" buttons even though I already used the same program to save user data before, when he needed to register:

HERE IS THE CODE FOR THE WHOLE ACTIVITY

```
FirebaseDatabase rootNode;
DatabaseReference reference;
TextInputEditText regnom_vol,regnum_vol,regmail_vol,regpassword_vol;

Spinner regniveau_vol;
Button mod_maths, mod_info;
//text des modules selectionnes par le volontaire pour chaque discipline
TextView mod_maths_selected, mod_info_selected;

//liste des modules en maths a partir de lesquelles le volontaire va selectionner

//LISTE DES MODULES DE MATHS
String[] listModMaths_lc;
String[] listModMaths_ma;
String[] listModMaths_doc;
String[] listModMaths;

//LISTE DES MODULES D'INFO
String[] listModInfo_lc;
String[] listModInfo_ma;
String[] listModInfo_doc;
String[] listModInfo;

//les element selectionne considere true
boolean[] chekedmodMaths;
boolean[] chekedmodInfo;


//La liste de modules selectionnes
ArrayList<Integer> modVol_Maths = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> modVol_Info = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.enregistrer_vol);

    mod_maths = findViewById(R.id.modules_maths);
    mod_info = findViewById(R.id.modules_info);
    mod_maths_selected = findViewById(R.id.selected_maths_mod);
    mod_info_selected = findViewById(R.id.selected_info_mod);

    regniveau_vol = findViewById(R.id.niveau_volontaire);

    //SELECTIONNER LE NIVEAU DU VOLONTAIRE
    List<String> niveau_Vol = new ArrayList<>();
    niveau_Vol.add(0, "Seclectionnez votre niveau d'etude");
    niveau_Vol.add("Licence");
    niveau_Vol.add("Master");
    niveau_Vol.add("Doctorat");

    //styler le spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> data;
    data = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, niveau_Vol);
    data.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    //RECUPERATION DES LISTES DE MODULES SELON LE NIVEAU DU STRING.XML
    listModMaths_lc = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Maths_LC);
    listModMaths_ma = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Maths_MA);
    listModMaths_doc = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Maths_DOC);
    //////////INFORMATIQUE///////////////////////////////////////////////
    listModInfo_lc = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Info_LC);
    listModInfo_ma = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Info_MA);
    listModInfo_doc = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Info_DOC);

    //Attacher data au spinnner (niveau etd)
    regniveau_vol.setAdapter(data);
    regniveau_vol.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("Selectionnez votre niveau d'etude")) {
                //On ne va rien faire
            } else {
                //ON selectionne un niveau
                String niv = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                //Afficher toast message du niveau selectionne
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Vous etes en " + niv, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equals("Licence"))
                {
                    listModMaths= listModMaths_lc;
                    listModInfo= listModInfo_lc;
                }
                else if(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("Master"))
                {
                    listModMaths=listModMaths_ma;
                    listModInfo= listModInfo_ma;
                }
                else
                {
                    listModMaths= listModMaths_doc;
                    listModInfo= listModInfo_doc;
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            if (regniveau_vol.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(""))
            {

            }
        }
    });

    //LES BOUTONS OK CLEAR ALL  ET CANCEL DE LISTE DES MODULES A COCHER
    mod_maths.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(enregistrer_vol.this);
            mBuilder.setTitle("Modules : Maths");
            mBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(listModMaths, chekedmodMaths, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position, boolean isChecked) {
                    //tester si le module est selectionne
                    if (isChecked) {
                        if (!modVol_Maths.contains(position))//si l'element courant ne fait partie de laliste des modules selectionne il faut l'ajouter
                        {
                            modVol_Maths.add(position);
                        } else //Si l'element selectionne fait partie deja de la liste des modules selectionnees apr le volontaire
                        {
                            modVol_Maths.remove(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            //Le bouton OK
            mBuilder.setCancelable(false);
            mBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String module = "";//Cette chaine de caractere va contenir la liste des modules qui se trouve dans la liste des modules selectionnes
                    for (int i = 0; i < modVol_Maths.size(); i++) {
                        module = module + listModMaths[modVol_Maths.get(i)];
                        if (i != modVol_Maths.size() - 1)//si l'element a la position i n'est pas le dernier on va faire un retour a la ligne
                        {
                            module = module + "\n ";
                        }
                    }
                    mod_maths_selected.setText(module);
                }
            });
            mBuilder.setNegativeButton("Annuler", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            mBuilder.setNeutralButton("Clear", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < chekedmodMaths.length; i++)//Verifier la liste des elements selectionne pour effacer la selection
                    {
                        chekedmodMaths[i] = false;
                        modVol_Maths.clear();//clear item in this list
                        mod_maths_selected.setText("");//changer le text des modules selectionnes apres avoir supprimer certains
                    }
                }
            });

            AlertDialog mDialog = mBuilder.create();
            mDialog.show();
        }
    });
    //LES BOUTONS OK CLEAR ALL  ET CANCEL DE LISTE DES MODULES A COCHER
    mod_info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(enregistrer_vol.this);
            mBuilder.setTitle("Modules : Informatique");
            mBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(listModInfo, chekedmodInfo, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position, boolean isChecked) {
                    //tester si le module est selectionne
                    if (isChecked) {
                        if (!modVol_Info.contains(position))//si l'element courant ne fait partie de la liste des modules selectionne il faut l'ajouter
                        {
                            modVol_Info.add(position);
                        } else //Si l'element selectionne fait partie deja de la liste des modules selectionnees apr le volontaire
                        {
                            modVol_Info.remove(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            //Le bouton OK
            mBuilder.setCancelable(false);
            mBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String module_info = "";//Cette chaine de caractere va contenir la liste des modules qui se trouve dans la liste des modules selectionnes
                    for (int i = 0; i < modVol_Info.size(); i++) {
                        module_info = module_info + listModInfo[modVol_Info.get(i)];
                        if (i != modVol_Info.size() - 1)//si l'element a la position i n'est pas le dernier on va faire un retour a la ligne
                        {
                            module_info = module_info + "\n ";
                        }
                    }
                    mod_info_selected.setText(module_info);
                }
            });
            mBuilder.setNegativeButton("Annuler", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            mBuilder.setNeutralButton("Clear", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < chekedmodInfo.length; i++)//Verifier la liste des elements selectionne pour effacer la selection
                    {
                        chekedmodInfo[i] = false;
                        modVol_Info.clear();//clear item in this list
                        mod_info_selected.setText("");//changer le text des modules selectionnes apres avoir supprimer certains
                    }
                }
            });

            AlertDialog mDialog = mBuilder.create();
            mDialog.show();
        }
    });

    // Donnees du xml a la l'activite "enregistrer_vol"
    regnom_vol = findViewById(R.id.nom_vol);
    regnum_vol = findViewById(R.id.num_vol);
    regpassword_vol = findViewById(R.id.password_vol);
    regmail_vol = findViewById(R.id.mail_vol);
    regniveau_vol = findViewById(R.id.niveau_volontaire);

}
//Validation des donnees etd
private Boolean validate_name() {
    String val = regnom_vol.getText().toString();
    if (val.isEmpty()) {
        regnom_vol.setError("Champs obligatoire");//affiche le message d'erreur si le champs est vide
        return false;
    } else {
        regnom_vol.setError(null);
        return true;
    }
}
private Boolean validate_mail() {
    String val = regmail_vol.getText().toString();
    String mail_syntaxe = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";

    if (val.isEmpty()) {
        regmail_vol.setError("Champs obligatoire");//affiche le message d'erreur si le champs est vide
        return false;
    } else if (!val.matches(mail_syntaxe)) {
        regmail_vol.setError("Adresse mail non valide");//affiche le message d'erreur si la syntaxe du mail est fausse
        return false;
    } else {
        regmail_vol.setError(null);
        //        nom.setErrorEnabled(false);// remove the error message after
        return true;
    }
}
private Boolean validate_password() {
    String val = regpassword_vol.getText().toString();
    String password_syntaxe = ".{4,}"; //au moins 4 caracteres n'impote lesquels

    if (val.isEmpty()) {
        regpassword_vol.setError("Champs obligatoire");//affiche le message d'erreur si le champs est vide
        return false;
    } else if (!val.matches(password_syntaxe)) {
        regpassword_vol.setError("Mot de passe faible");//affiche le message d'erreur si la syntaxe du mail est fausse
        return false;
    } else {
        regpassword_vol.setError(null);
        return true;
    }
}
private Boolean validate_num() {
    String val = regnum_vol.getText().toString();
    if (val.isEmpty()) {
        regnum_vol.setError("Champs obligatoire");//affiche le message d'erreur si le champs est vide
        return false;
    } else {
        regnum_vol.setError(null);
        return true;
    }
}

public void register_vol(View view)
{
    if(!validate_name() | !validate_num()| !validate_mail()| !validate_password())
        return;
    else
    {
        rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        reference = rootNode.getReference("vol");

        //getting all the values
        String name = regnom_vol.getText().toString();
        String mail = regmail_vol.getText().toString();
        String password = regpassword_vol.getText().toString();
        String num = regnum_vol.getText().toString();
        String niveau = regniveau_vol.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String maths= mod_maths_selected.getText().toString();
        String info= mod_info_selected.getText().toString();
        Volontaires volontaire= new Volontaires(name,num,niveau,mail,password,maths,info);
        reference.child(num).setValue(volontaire);

        //Afficher profil volontaire
        startActivity(new Intent(enregistrer_vol.this,identification_fragment.class));

    }
}
```

}

Comment: I believe that here `AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(edit_profil_vol.this);` you should use your activity/fragment context. is 

Also please show your whole code of this activity/fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialized **mod_info_selected** object?

You have to get this view from layout.. you currently do have line like this

```
mod_info_selected = findViewById(R.id.mod_info_selected)
```

And that's why your app crashed

Comment: mod_info_selected   is a TextView how am I supposed to initialize it?

Comment: I just updated my answer. Now it should be clear

Comment: Yes I already have this line just as I already said this code work just fine in registration but here no it crashes every time

Comment: @DidyouknowTHAT You DON'T have that tile in code that you posted.

Comment: I just post the whole code of the activity